# Can react-native-desktop access the filesystem?

Tags: react-native

There are react-native projects for:

- [Linux](https://github.com/status-im/react-native-desktop)
- [macOS](https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-macos)
- [Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows)

If I have a file that already exists on the filesystem, can I read it from react-native-* ?

If not, how can otherwise get some data from a text file on the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

If to talk regarding [react-native-desktop](https://github.com/status-im/react-native-desktop) you can try to use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/status-im/react-native-fs) fork with `desktop` platform support.

At the time of this answer writing it has implementation of only 2 methods:
[RNFSManager::readFile](https://github.com/status-im/react-native-fs/blob/master/desktop/rnfsmanager.cpp#L87) and [RNFSManager::moveFile](https://github.com/status-im/react-native-fs/blob/master/desktop/rnfsmanager.cpp#L106)

The only known sample of usage can be found [there](https://github.com/status-im/status-react/blob/develop-desktop/package.json#L18).

In package.json of project based on react-native-desktop it should be referenced as:

```
"desktopExternalModules": [
    "node_modules/react-native-fs/desktop"
],
...
"react-native-fs": "git+https://github.com/status-im/react-native-fs.git",
...
```

Also `react-native-desktop` supports OS X as well.